# Why are @Configuration classes wrapped by the CGLIB proxy with the ConfigurationClassEnhancer class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

When I read and debug spring source, I find that the `@Configuration` classes are wrapped by the CGLIB proxy with the ConfigurationClassEnhancer class, I don`t understand the reason of the design, can somebody explain it?

Answer (score 0):

To handle situations like below.

- @Configuration classes contains bean definitions via @Bean
  annotations
- Many of the beans have collaborators, so we inject those
  collaborators(which are also beans) using standard java method
  semantics
- So, every time datasource() is called, spring does not create new
  instance(since it is Singleton).
- This happens because @Configuartion class is proxied and it contains
  the logic to check if beans are already in ApplicationContext

  ```
  @Configuration
  public class MyConfig{

  @Bean
  public MyDao1 Dao1(){
      MyDao1 d1 = new MyDao1();
      d1.setDataSource(datasource());
      return d1;
  }

  @Bean
  public MyDao2 Dao2(){
      MyDao1 d2 = new MyDao2();
      d2.setDataSource(datasource());
      return d2;
  }

  @Bean
  public Datasource datasource(){
    DataSource ds = new DataSource();
    return ds;
  }

  }
  ```

Note: @Component classes can also define beans via @Beans, but scenario like above will definitely cause  problems since bean calls don't get intercepted via proxy in that case.

Comment: I define a @Configuration named AppConfig and cglib create a proxy class named AppConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e53ce80a with AppConfig, i can`t understand the proxy class, And can`t read the sources of the proxy class, do you have some skills to understand them?

Comment: I would just understand the intent of proxy class, rather than all it's messy details.