# How does Spring handle beans when used in a different method in the same configuration file

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to wrap my head around Spring annotation-based bean initialization. So I have this class where I have multiple bean declarations and some beans are required by other beans. The question I have is if I directly used a bean method within another bean factory method would Spring correctly handle it and inject the required bean or would I end up creating multiple instances of the injected bean?

Sample Code

```java
@Configuration
class Config {
    
    @Bean
    public SomeBean someBean() {
        // some builder code
        return someBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public AnotherBean anotherBean() {
        return anotherBeanBuilder
            .withSomeBean(someBean())
            .build();
    }
}
```

So if I rephrase my question based on the above example, what I want to know is basically when I use `anotherBean()` in some other place would spring correctly use the already created `someBean` or would it end up creating multiple instances of `SomeBean`.

Comment: Yes it does. But it is better to just inject the bean into the method as an argument as this will make it easier for Spring to figure out dependencies between beans and provide the correct setup order.

Comment: Sometimes you don't have a choice, for example in some configurers such as SpringMVC or Spring Security. When you do have a choice, do as @M.Deinum suggests

Comment: Spring MVC prevents nothing of the sorts, nor does Spring Security (especially the newer configuration version).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring creates special proxies for `@Configuration` classes. In fact, the method is only called once. It's quite easy to verify your hypothesis yourself:

```
@Configuration
class Config {
    
    @Bean
    public SomeBean someBean() {
        final SomeBean bean;
        System.out.println("created someBean: " + bean);
        return bean;
    }

    @Bean
    public AnotherBean anotherBean() {
        System.out.println(someBean()); // SomeBean@cafe0420 (example)
        System.out.println(someBean());
        System.out.println(someBean());
        return new AnotherBean(someBean());
    }
}

class SomeBean {}
class AnotherBean { AnotherBean(SomeBean bean) {} }
```

Output:

```
created someBean: SomeBean@cafe0420
SomeBean@cafe0420
SomeBean@cafe0420
SomeBean@cafe0420
```

So as you can see, calling a method of a configuration class will return the same single bean instance (it doesn't actually call the method at all).

Additional resources:

- https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/core/aop/proxying.html
- [why are @Configuration classes wraped by the cglib proxy with the ConfigurationClassEnhancer class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55441404/why-are-configuration-classes-wraped-by-the-cglib-proxy-with-the-configurationc)
- http://www.javabyexamples.com/cglib-proxying-in-spring-configuration